How to read currently executing lines of nc program in TwinCAT 2 NC I?
Main goal is to display currently executing lines at C# app. At least I want them as variable in ST so then I could read them from C#.
I found from Beckhoff's doc this article and in general it satisfies my goal, but I couldn't manage to do this neither from C# app via AdsClient.Read and ReadAny nor from plc program using TcSystem.ADS.ADSREAD function block. I tried 801 port (default port for tc2) and 500 (as written in docs) but both gave me the same error.
In C# I get ADS-error 0x701 (Service is not supported by the server.) and in plc program I get 0x745 (errID 1861) Timeout has occurred – the remote terminal is not responding in the specified ADS timeout. The route setting of the remote terminal may be configured incorrectly.
I tried 0x23000002 as index group value and 0x20000001 as index offset. 
Upd1: How it worked in C#
TcAdsClient tcAdsClient = new TcAdsClient();
tcAdsClient.Connect("192.168.65.102.1.1", 500);
try
{
    string res = tcAdsClient.ReadAnyString(indexGroup, indexOffset, 80, Encoding.Default);
    ConsoleOutput += res;
    tcAdsClient.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}

But if I try this it gives me an error 0x701
int sHandle = tcAdsClient.AddDeviceNotification(indexGroup, indexOffset, _AdsStream, 0, 80, AdsTransMode.OnChange, 250, 0, null);

How I tried in ST (fbADSRead.ERRID shows 1861 error all the time):
fbADSRead:      ADSREAD;
sBuffer:        DWORD;
bExec:          BOOL;
----
IF bExec THEN
 fbADSRead(
            NETID       :='192.168.65.102.1.1',
            PORT        :=500,
            IDXGRP      :=16#2302,
            IDXOFFS     :=16#20000001,
            LEN         :=80,
            DESTADDR    :=sBuffer,
            READ        :=TRUE,
            TMOUT       :=t#5s);
END_IF

In case link is not working TwinCAT 2 -> TwinCAT NC -> TwinCAT NC I -> Appendix -> Display of the parts program. Reading of the current NC line via ADS.

If I understood the docs correctly, you are supposed to set index group to 0x2300 + Channel ID, so it would be 0x2302, not 0x23000002.
If that does not help, please, post your code

Ok, I don't know why, but when I tried it by myself (with 0x2302) it didn't work. But now, it does (with ReadAnyString in C#). But I can't read it with AdsNotification (I guess because it has no variable name) and that's why I get 0x701 in C#. So, I think I need store value in ST var and read it from C#. I'll post how I tried reading in ST.
